# 3 collinear points - some bugs

Tags: c++, struct

can anybody tell me why it doesn't works for input `0 0 0 0 0 0`?

```
struct pPoint
{
    float x, y;
};

struct line
{
    pPoint x1, x2, x3;
};

bool judge(line& x)
{
    if (x.x1.x == x.x2.x == x.x3.x)
        return true;
    else
    {
        if (x.x1.y == x.x2.y == x.x3.y)
            return true;
        else
        {
            float a = (x.x1.y - x.x2.y) / (x.x1.x - x.x2.x);
            float b = x.x1.y - x.x1.x*a;
            if (x.x3.y == a*x.x3.x + b)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    line x;
cin >> x.x1.x >> x.x1.y >> x.x2.x >> x.x2.y >> x.x3.x >> x.x3.y;
cout << (judge(x) ? "YES" : "NO") << "\n";

    return 0;
    }
```

it checks if 3 points are collinear, it is working good, but for input 
`0 0 0 0 0 0` 
it says `NO` or crashes, it works fine for `1 1 1 1 1 1` etc.
When I debugged it, it just skips first `if` in judge.

Comment: I don't think you need second else statement. The logic of comparing corresponding `x,y` points should be sufficient for collinear points. Isn't it ? Not sure why you are calculating slope and other operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It not working because in this line:

```
if (x.x1.x == x.x2.x == x.x3.x)
```

You are first compering int to int `x.x1.x == x.x2.x` and then you are compering int with bool
bool == x.x3.x.

You must compare every of this points with other like this:

```
if (x.x1.x == x.x2.x && x.x2.x == x.x3.x && x.x1.x == x.x2.x )
```

If you change it everywhere it should work;)

Answer (score 0):

`a == b == c` does not work as you desired because of the operation [priority](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm). It can actually be written to: `(a == b) == c` because associativity of `==` is `left-to-right`. The first `(a == b)` equals to `true` when `a=b=c=0`, while `c = 0`, so`true != c`, that's why the whole expression failed. Please use `if ((a == b) && (a == c))` instead.

It worked when `a = b = c = 1`, that's because `(a == b) = true`, and `c = 1`, and the Boolean value `true` equals to `1` too, so the expression succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x.x1.y == x.x2.y == x.x3.y)
```

This design does not perform what you expect from it.

`x.x1.y == x.x2.y == x.x3.y` is the same as `x.x1.y == (x.x2.y == x.x3.y)` and `x.x1.y == (x.x2.y == x.x3.y ? 1 : 0)`

```
if (x.x1.x == x.x2.x && x.x2.x == x.x3.x && x.x1.x == x.x2.x )
```

is that you need.